# How do I create an array with the input values from an array of input Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everytime I click I concatenate components and render them to the screen. That works well. But what if I want to take the data(values) from those components and put them within the same array , CompList (or another array)? To be clear, I would all the values in the different input boxes to correspond to their own element within the array ex: if elementName = "" inside index 1 of the array, then "" is the value at the index. How would I go about doing this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Comp from './Comp';
import Button from './button';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    CompList: [],
    elementName: ""
  }

  AddComp = event => {

    this.setState(
      {CompList: this.state.CompList.concat(this.state.elementName)}
    );
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.CompList.map(el => <Comp/>)}
        <Button AddComp = {this.AddComp}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the button to click that appends the component. AddComp is sent to this component.

```
import React from 'react';

const button = props =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <div onClick = {props.AddComp}>
                Clickme
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default button;
```

And here is the component itself (the component that gets iterated and displayed). I hope Im being clear enough. If needed Ill gladly post additional information.

```
import React from 'react';

const Comp = props =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <input/>
            <div>
                100
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Comp;
```

Comment: I would like to help, but to be honest I'm not sure what you are trying to do:P Could you perhaps rephrase your question or explicate a bit more:)

Comment: Sure. So I have a dynamic list of components(The component contains an input tag). Every time I click the button it adds an input component. After I add enough components(no limit), I would like to type in the fields then save all of the data (including empty strings) to an array of it's own to be uses for later. I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: The new array should have the data listed exactly as it's typed in the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some research on how `.concat()` [works in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), it implies you need to send an array (`array1.concat(array2)`) and it will combine them. [You may be looking for `.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which takes an element.

In addition, `this.setState({ array: array.push(element) })` or `this.setState({ array: array.concat(array2) })` will not work because both `.push()` and `.concat()` return the new length of the array, so you'll end up setting array to a number.

So, to do the task that you're looking for, you'll want to have your onClick function look something like this:

```
AddComp = event => {
  var tempCompList = this.state.CompList; //this creates a duplicate array
  tempCompList.push(this.state.elementName); //this needs to be separate or we will set a variable to an integer on accident

  this.setState(
    {CompList: tempCompList} //where we set the original array to the duplicate array
  );
}
```